# Difference between View and property in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

can any one explain the difference between view and property in google analytics in simple terms? I am unable to understand this difference.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hierarchy of Accounts, Users, Properties, and Views](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618) is as such.

- A User (you) can have many Accounts.
- An Account can have many Properties (originally called web properties).
- A Property can have many Views (originally called Profiles).

Different Views can have different filters applied with them and differen session settings. You send data to Google Analytics at a property (`UA-XXXXX-Y`) level.